# org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject org.json.JSONException: Value

Tags: android, arrays, json, android-studio, android-fragments

Trying to pull json data but not able to pull json data object
Wasted 1 Day to solve this but i am getting **org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject**

What is this error? Any one face same issue let me know Array of Array
Below is my code which i tried.

searched in google not got solution

**Updated** 
i am getting all Array of array in all data is coming in same output ExerciseChapters. can check what output 'i am getting output'

The json output what iam getting what mistake i am doing

```
 if (param_get_ServiceCallResult.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.GET_USER_MYEXERCISES)) {

                OutputResponseModel outputResponseModel = gson.fromJson(response, OutputResponseModel.class);

                if (outputResponseModel.isSuccess()) {
                    //JSONObject jSONObject1 = new JSONObject(response);
                    //JsonArray jArray = jSONObject1.getJSONArray("data");
                    exerciseChaptersArray = new ArrayList<ExerciseChapters>();

                    try {
                        JSONObject base = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray dataContent = base.getJSONArray("data");
                        for (int i = 0; i < dataContent.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject eachData = dataContent.getJSONObject(i);

                            testPaperResponseModelObj = new TestPaperResponseModel();
                            testPaperResponseModelObj.setCourseId(eachData.getString("CourseId"));
                            testPaperResponseModelObj.setCourseName(eachData.getString("CourseName"));
                            testPaperResponseModelObj.setCourseIcon(eachData.getString("CourseIcon"));
                            testPaperResponseModelObj.setDownloadedCount(eachData.getString("DownloadedCount"));
                            testPaperResponseModelObj.setRemainingCount(eachData.getString("RemainingCount"));

                            testPaperResponseModelArray.add(testPaperResponseModelObj);

                            String courseId = eachData.getString("CourseId");
                            JSONArray exerciseChapters = eachData.getJSONArray("ExerciseChapters");


                            for (int j = 0; j < exerciseChapters.length(); j++) {
                                JSONObject eachDataexerciseChapters = exerciseChapters.getJSONObject(j);
                                ExerciseChapters exerciseChaptersObj = new ExerciseChapters();
                                exerciseChaptersObj.setCourseId(courseId);
                                exerciseChaptersObj.setCourseChapterId(eachDataexerciseChapters.getString("CourseChapterId"));
                                exerciseChaptersObj.setCourseChapterName(eachDataexerciseChapters.getString("CourseChapterName"));
                                exerciseChaptersObj.setCourseChapterNumber(eachDataexerciseChapters.getString("CourseChapterNumber"));
                                exerciseChaptersObj.setIsFileDownloaded(eachDataexerciseChapters.getString("IsFileDownloaded"));
                                exerciseChaptersArray.add(exerciseChaptersObj);

                            }
                            testPaperResponseModelArray.get(i).setExerciseChapters(exerciseChaptersArray);
                        }



                        Log.i("testPaperRespons***", testPaperResponseModelObj.toString());


                    } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

**i am getting output**

```
TestPaperResponseModel{CourseId='28', CourseName='Computer Science', CourseIcon='28_fcIcon.jpg', DownloadedCount='0', RemainingCount='0', exerciseChapters=[ExerciseChapters{CourseId='1', CourseChapterId='1', CourseChapterName='Reproduction In Organism', CourseChapterNumber='Chapter-1', IsFileDownloaded='true'}, ExerciseChapters{CourseId='1', CourseChapterId='2', CourseChapterName='Sexual Reproduction In Flowering Plants', CourseChapterNumber='Chapter-2', IsFileDownloaded='true'}, ExerciseChapters{CourseId='1', CourseChapterId='3', CourseChapterName='Human Reproduction', CourseChapterNumber='Chapter-3', IsFileDownloaded='false'}, ExerciseChapters{CourseId='1', CourseChapterId='922', CourseChapterName='Unsolved Guess Paper 1', CourseChapterNumber='Paper- 1', IsFileDownloaded='false'}, ExerciseChapters{CourseId='1', CourseChapterId='923', CourseChapterName='Unsolved Guess Paper - 2', CourseChapterNumber='Paper - 2', IsFileDownloaded='false'}, ExerciseChapters{CourseId='1', CourseChapterId='924', CourseChapterName='Unsolved Guess Paper - 3', CourseChapterNumber='Paper - 3', IsFileDownloaded='false'}, ExerciseChapters{CourseId='3', CourseChapterId='928', CourseChapterName='Unsolved Guess Paper - 1', CourseChapterNumber='Paper - 1', IsFileDownloaded='false'}, ExerciseChapters{CourseId='3', CourseChapterId='929', CourseChapterName='Unsolved Guess Paper - 2', CourseChapterNumber='Paper - 2', IsFileDownloaded='false'}, ExerciseChapters{CourseId='3', CourseChapterId='930', CourseChapterName='Unsolved Guess Paper - 3', CourseChapterNumber='Paper - 3', IsFileDownloaded='false'}, ExerciseChapters{CourseId='6', CourseChapterId='935', CourseChapterName='Unsolved Guess Paper - 1', CourseChapterNumber='Paper - 1', IsFileDownloaded='false'}, ExerciseChapters{CourseId='6', CourseChapterId='936', CourseChapterName='Unsolved Guess Paper - 2', CourseChapterNumber='Paper - 2', IsFileDownloaded='false'}, ExerciseChapters{CourseId='6', CourseChapterId='937', CourseChapterName='Unsolved Guess Paper - 3', CourseChapterNumber='Paper - 3', IsFileDownloaded='false'}, ExerciseChapters{CourseId='10', CourseChapterId='944', CourseChapterName='Unsolved Guess Paper - 1', CourseChapterNumber='Paper - 1', IsFileDownloaded='false'}, ExerciseChapters{CourseId='10', CourseChapterId='945', CourseChapterName='Unsolved Guess Paper - 2', CourseChapterNumber='Paper - 2', IsFileDownloaded='false'}, ExerciseChapters{CourseId='10', CourseChapterId='946', CourseChapterName='Unsolved Guess Paper - 3', CourseChapterNumber='Paper - 3', IsFileDownloaded='false'}, ExerciseChapters{CourseId='11', CourseChapterId='947', CourseChapterName='Unsolved Guess Paper - 1', CourseChapterNumber='Paper - 1', IsFileDownloaded='false'}, ExerciseChapters{CourseId='11', CourseChapterId='948', CourseChapterName='Unsolved Guess Paper - 2', CourseChapterNumber='Paper - 2', IsFileDownloaded='false'}, ExerciseChapters{CourseId='11', CourseChapterId='949', CourseChapterName='Unsolved Guess Paper - 3', CourseChapterNumber='Paper - 3', IsFileDownloaded='false'}, ExerciseChapters{CourseId='12', CourseChapterId='990', CourseChapterName='Unsolved Guess Paper - 1', CourseChapterNumber='Paper - 1', IsFileDownloaded='false'}, ExerciseChapters{CourseId='12', CourseChapterId='991', CourseChapterName='Unsolved Guess Paper - 2', CourseChapterNumber='Paper - 2', IsFileDownloaded='false'}, ExerciseChapters{CourseId='12', CourseChapterId='992', CourseChapterName='Unsolved Guess Paper - 3', CourseChapterNumber='Paper - 3', IsFileDownloaded='false'}]}
```

**Json Output**

```
{
       "isSuccess": true,
      "message": "",
      "data": [
        {
          "CourseId": 1,
          "CourseName": "Biology",
          "CourseIcon": "1_fcIcon.jpg",
          "DownloadedCount": 2,
          "RemainingCount": 4,
          "ExerciseChapters": [
            {
              "CourseChapterId": 1,
              "CourseChapterName": "Reproduction In Organism",
              "CourseChapterNumber": "Chapter-1",
              "IsFileDownloaded": true
            },
            {
              "CourseChapterId": 2,
              "CourseChapterName": "Sexual Reproduction In Flowering Plants",
              "CourseChapterNumber": "Chapter-2",
              "IsFileDownloaded": true
            },
            {
              "CourseChapterId": 3,
              "CourseChapterName": "Human Reproduction",
              "CourseChapterNumber": "Chapter-3",
              "IsFileDownloaded": false
            },
            {
              "CourseChapterId": 922,
              "CourseChapterName": "Unsolved Guess Paper 1",
              "CourseChapterNumber": "Paper- 1",
              "IsFileDownloaded": false
            },
            {
              "CourseChapterId": 923,
              "CourseChapterName": "Unsolved Guess Paper - 2",
              "CourseChapterNumber": "Paper - 2",
              "IsFileDownloaded": false
            },
            {
              "CourseChapterId": 924,
              "CourseChapterName": "Unsolved Guess Paper - 3",
              "CourseChapterNumber": "Paper - 3",
              "IsFileDownloaded": false
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "CourseId": 3,
          "CourseName": "Chemistry",
          "CourseIcon": "3_fcIcon.jpg",
          "DownloadedCount": 0,
          "RemainingCount": 3,
          "ExerciseChapters": [
            {
              "CourseChapterId": 928,
              "CourseChapterName": "Unsolved Guess Paper - 1",
              "CourseChapterNumber": "Paper - 1",
              "IsFileDownloaded": false
            },
            {
              "CourseChapterId": 929,
              "CourseChapterName": "Unsolved Guess Paper - 2",
              "CourseChapterNumber": "Paper - 2",
              "IsFileDownloaded": false
            },
            {
              "CourseChapterId": 930,
              "CourseChapterName": "Unsolved Guess Paper - 3",
              "CourseChapterNumber": "Paper - 3",
              "IsFileDownloaded": false
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "CourseId": 28,
          "CourseName": "Computer Science",
          "CourseIcon": "28_fcIcon.jpg",
          "DownloadedCount": 0,
          "RemainingCount": 0,
          "ExerciseChapters": []
        }
      ]
     }
```

**TestPaperResponseModel .java**

public class TestPaperResponseModel implements Serializable {

```
private String CourseId;
private String CourseName;
private String CourseIcon;
private String DownloadedCount;
private String RemainingCount;
private List<ExerciseChapters> exerciseChapters;
```

}

Comment: your "data" is json Array but you mention its a jsonObject  (                    String dataContent = jSONObject1.getString("data");)@Rao's

Comment: use this line String dataContent = jSONObject1.getJSONArray("data");

Comment: Can you Tell us What's on TestPapersFragment.parseResponse line no 210 ?

Comment: @Dipalishah it contents Data key. updated above

Answer (score 1):

```
if (outputResponseModel.isSuccess()) {
                JSONObject jSONObject1 = new JSONObject(response);
                JsonArray jArray = jSONObject1.getJSONArray("data");

                try {
                    for (JsonElement obj : jArray) {
                        testPaperResponseModelObj = gson.fromJson(obj, TestPaperResponseModel.class);
                        testPaperResponseModelArray.add(testPaperResponseModelObj);

                        JSONObject jsssonDashboardChildContent = new JSONObject(dataContent);
                        JsonArray Jarray = jsssonDashboardChildContent.getJSONArray("ExerciseChapters");

                        exerciseChaptersArray = new ArrayList<ExerciseChapters>();
                        for (JsonElement obj1 : Jarray) {
                            ExerciseChapters exerciseChaptersobj = gson.fromJson(obj1, ExerciseChapters.class);
                            exerciseChaptersArray.add(exerciseChaptersobj);
                        }



                        if (testPaperResponseModelObj != null) {
                            testPaperResponseModelObj.setExerciseChapters(exerciseChaptersArray);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

try to get the array like this

```
        JSONObject base = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray dataContent = base.getJSONArray("data");
        for(int i=0;i<dataContent.length();i++){
            JSONObject eachData = dataContent.getJSONObject(i);
            eachData.getString("CourseId");
            JSONArray ExerciseChapters = base.getJSONArray("ExerciseChapters");
            for(int j=0;j<ExerciseChapters.length();j++){
                // do what you want to do with you array
            }
        }
```

Comment: Updated i am getting all data in same list. It is not inserting as per course id

Comment: I don't get what you saying, but if you want to convert you JSON to Object try to use google GSON, you can create nested object and easily convert your JSON to your custom object, easy to use and you going to have clean code :) https://github.com/google/gson